# cp with reflink flag: how to determine if reflink is possible?

Tags: btrfs, glibc, coreutils

When I copy a file using reflink option, e.g.,

```
cp --reflink foo bar
```

how and what stage in execution of cp determines if the underneath file system supports COW. I tried looking into `coreutils/src/cp.c` but couldn't find the specific system call/ ioctl or any other method which determines COW capability and accordingly proceeds for cp execution / reports error:

> cp: failed to clone 'bar' from 'foo': Bad address

In short, I am looking for how resolution of `--reflink=auto` option happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c?h=v8.25#n1197) calls a function called [`clone_file`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/copy.c?h=v8.25#n321) if the reflink option is set to “always” or “auto”, and falls back to copying if reflink is “always” (and goes directly to copying if reflink is off). `clone_file` calls the `BTRFS_IOC_CLONE` [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl). So there's no testing whether the system supports copy-on-write, it just attempts the BTRFS method.